# Number of ways of resolving a composite number into factors prime to each other

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways in which a composite number $N$ can be resolved into two factors which are prime to each other if $N$ is of the form $2^23^25^27^2$.

According to a formula, the answer is $2^{n-1}= 8$, but I am getting only $7$ possible cases. What is the eighth one?

Comment: Did you forget $1\cdot N$?

Comment: But are $1$ and $N$ really prime to each other ? Doesn’t $1$ divide $N$ ?

Comment: $1$ is coprime to every integer, for there is no prime dividing $1$.